# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when running uispec4j test case

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, runtime-error, testcase, uispec4j

I am getting the above error message (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError) when running UISpec test case in Eclipse as well as IntelliJ.

I have sun/oracle JDK 1.7 installed.

The full report of the error is

> ```
> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> > sun.awt.motif.MToolkit.init(Ljava/lang/String;)V    at
> > sun.awt.motif.MToolkit.init(Native Method)  at
> > sun.awt.motif.MToolkit.<init>(MToolkit.java:146)    at
> > sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
> >     at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)     at
> > java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)     at
> > org.uispec4j.interception.toolkit.UISpecToolkit.buildUnderlyingToolkit(UISpecToolkit.java:128)
> >     at
> > org.uispec4j.interception.toolkit.UISpecToolkit.setUp(UISpecToolkit.java:39)
> >     at
> > org.uispec4j.interception.toolkit.UISpecToolkit.<init>(UISpecToolkit.java:24)
> >     at org.uispec4j.UISpec4J.initToolkit(UISpec4J.java:39)  at
> > org.uispec4j.UISpec4J.init(UISpec4J.java:31)    at
> > org.uispec4j.UISpecTestCase.<clinit>(UISpecTestCase.java:31)    at
> > sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
> >     at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:131)     at
> > junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:114)     at
> > junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:75)     at
> > com.intellij.junit3.TestRunnerUtil.createClassOrMethodSuite(TestRunnerUtil.java:140)
> >     at
> > com.intellij.junit3.TestRunnerUtil.getTestSuite(TestRunnerUtil.java:79)
> >     at
> > com.intellij.junit3.JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
> >     at
> > com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
> >     at
> > com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
> >     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> > sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
> > com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
> > 
> > Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

If anyone had experienced the same issue please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a known Java Bug: [6996291](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6996291).

The issue seems to be caused by **UISpec** explicitly loading `sun.awt.motif.MToolkit` on Linux, while this toolkit is no longer available in JDK 1.7. See if there is a way to disable it in the UISpec configuration or report the issue to the developers.

As a workaround you can use Oracle JDK 1.6.0.

Comment: You are really correct. The problem was due to the non-availability of the toolkit in JDK 1.7. But when I run > javap sun.awt.Motif.MToolkit it showed the class declaration. So I thought the class is available in JDK1.7. Also, I reported the problem to UISpec developer team. Once again, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, but using openjdk (under Linux Mint). Removing openjdk and installing sun-java6-jdk instead (with the Linux-Software-Manager) solved the problem.